# For $R>0$ , let $\gamma_R$ the arc of circumference with center in 0 and radius R (from R to -R), contained in upper half-plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

For $R>0$ , let $\gamma_R$ the arc of circumference with center in 0 and radius R (from R to -R), contained in upper half-plane.

Show:

$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz = 0$

Let $\epsilon >0$. I consider $\gamma_R: [0,\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, such that $\gamma_R(t)=Re^{it}$.

Then:

$|\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz-0|=|\int_{\gamma_R} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}dz|$

I'm not really sure how to calculate this integral.

Comment: What did you do so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm still looking for some way to calculate the integral without using the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: Thus I suppose you cannot use the Residue Theorem and its different corollaries, right?

Comment: @DonAntonio 
Something like what they mention below.

Because I remember that Cauchy's integral formula applies to closed curves. And in this case, we have an arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) (which is pretty easy to prove in case you haven't done that):

$$\left|\int_{\gamma_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} dz\right|\le \max\left|\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2}\right|\cdot \ell(\gamma_R)=\frac{1}{R^2}\cdot \pi R\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{}0$$

with $\;\ell(\gamma_R)=\,$ the length of $\;\gamma_R\;$